# Personal notes to an intermediate report/performance review from a member of the management

Tags: recruitment, performance-reviews, certification, interim-report

As part of a project that I have managed (in the role of an entrepreneur), I have worked closely with a member of the management (N + 3) within the large enterprise I work for. He agreed to add a personal note as part of my intermediate report/performance review.

Unfortunately, he recently left the company before he could add this.
Still, he requested me to send him *something* so he could sign it.

Since I do not want to formulate the personal notes myself, because I simply feel bad in writing a nice resume about myself, the question arises to me what an alternative proof of achievement could look like.

I'm looking for ideas or alternatives to express his recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unfortunately, he recently left the company before he could add this.
>   Still, he requested me to send him something so he could sign it.
>
> Since I do not want to formulate the personal notes myself, because I
>   simply feel bad in writing a nice resume about myself, the question
>   arises to me what an alternative proof of achievement could look like.
>
> I'm looking for ideas or alternatives to express his recommendation.

Other than finding someone else who can write a recommendation, it appears that you have no choice other than to write it yourself, or abandon the idea altogether.

Try to construct a recommendation that you think this member of management would have written himself. Don't be shy - you certainly would expect praise for the work you have done.